# C++ How to remove 0 values from array without using vector

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

As the title says I want to remove the elements in my array that contain 0.

When the user prompt an integer that's the same the program rejects the user input and will automatically put a 0 there instead but I want it to be removed.

Here is my current output in an array of 20

```
25     35     50     23     95     55      9     85     45      0     
97     56      0     33     75      0    101     86    100      0
```

and here is my desire output with the same user prompt

```
25    35    50    23    95   55    85    45    97   
56    33    75    86   100
```

Comment: What happened to the 9?

Comment: `std::remove` should be fine.

Comment: you should give it a try first and then show what you have done before asking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still prefer using `std::vector` although this question mentions "without using vector". But let's just try doing so with array anyway.

```
int int_array[20] = {/*...*/};

int* last_ptr = std::remove(std::begin(int_array), std::end(int_array), 0);

for (int* it = int_array ; it != last_ptr ; ++it)
    cout << *it << endl;
```

As convention, the resulting `last_ptr` points to the location one pass the end of the resulting array.

Since it is an array, the actual array size does not change. All we can do is to ignore the unused part of the array.

Comment: So what I do is to make a pointer and if that pointer has a value of 0 it'll remove it. Another question is if you can do it without using pointers and read it through a for loop

Comment: Since `std::remove` uses iterator, and iterator of raw array is pointer, pointer is essential here. Also, using iterators like this is common to all array, `std::array`, `std::vector`, `std::list` etc. Array indexing is the alternative way to access an array, but array indexing is by definition short hand of pointer arithmetic according to the language standard.